# Issues with properly formatted json string

Tags: php, json

I am having issues with a properly formatted json string, I believe.  I am wondering if it is due to the construction of the query string, but it looks right to me, unless it's an issue with the double brackets that are in the encoded json string below.  Looking for an extra set of eyes.

Before json encoding, var_dump($considerationCodes) looks like:

```
array (size=2)
  8 => 
    array (size=13)
      67 => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
      41 => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
      42 => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
```

print json_encode($considerationCodes); looks like:

```
$considerationCodes = 
{"8": {"67":  [[  {"id":"64","description":"string description..."},{"id":"65","description":"string description..., "},{"id":"66","description":"string description..."}  ]]  , "41":  [[  {"id":"64","description":"string description..."},{"id":"65","description":"string description..., "},{"id":"66","description":"string description..."}  ]] }}
```

Json structure how it is expected/accepted (tested and works with raw data):

```
['8']['67']['64'] = "string description...";
['8']['67']['65'] = "string description...";
['8']['67']['66'] = "string description...";
['8']['41']['64'] = "string description...";
['8']['41’]['65'] = "string description...";
['8']['41']['66'] = "string description...";
...etc
```

And this is how I submit the json encode (tested and works with raw data):

```
return $this->renderText(json_encode( $considerationCodes[$appCode][$reasonCode] ) );
```

When I look at the results of this json submission (a multiple choice select input), it looks like:

```
[Object][object][Object][object][Object][object][Object][object]
```

What am I missing?

EDIT:

This is how I have constructed my arrays:

```
$reason_codes_ids = array();
        foreach($all_reason_codes as $key => $values) {
            $reason_codes_ids[] = $values['id'];
        }
        //wrap the consideration_info into each reason_id:        
        $codes_with_reasons = array();
        foreach($reason_codes_ids as $value){
            foreach($consideration_info as $key => $value1){
                $codes_with_reasons[$value][$key] = $value1;
            }
        }
        //the above results in: ['reason-code-id']['consideration-code-id'] = "consideration-code-answer":
        //next, get the declined_app_status:
        $declinedAppStatus = 8;
        //then wrap the above results in a wraper for the declined application-code
        $declinedConsiderationCodes = array();
        foreach($codes_with_reasons as $key => $value)
        {
            $declinedConsiderationCodes[$declinedAppStatus][$key]=[$value];
        }
        $considerationCodes = $declinedConsiderationCodes;
```

and:

```
$consideration_info =

array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '64' (length=2)
      'description' => string 'string...' (length=35)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '65' (length=2)
      'description' => string ''string...' (length=143)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '66' (length=2)
      'description' => string ''string...' (length=143)

$reason_codes_ids =

array (size=13)
  0 => string '67' (length=2)
  1 => string '41' (length=2)
  2 => string '42' (length=2)
  3 => string '43' (length=2)
  4 => string '44' (length=2)
  5 => string '45' (length=2)
  6 => string '46' (length=2)
  7 => string '47' (length=2)
  8 => string '48' (length=2)
  9 => string '49' (length=2)
  10 => string '50' (length=2)
  11 => string '51' (length=2)
  12 => string '68' (length=2)
```

Comment: You have forgotten to post what happens with that JSON inside `$this->renderText()`

Comment: That looks like the JSON is being incorrectly handled by whatever Javascript you have listening on the other end - "[object Object]" is what you'll get if you cast a JS Object to a string.

Comment: As I mentioned, I have tested it with raw data, and the javascript works on the other end.  Therefore, I'm rather confident that the problem lies in the format in which it is being submitted. As for what happens inside $this->renderText(), I'll check, but I believe it is the same result mentioned above (the contents of json_encode($considerationCodes);

Comment: Have you tried to pass `true` as second parameter to `json_encode` ? This bit me several times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With proper formatting and indentation, your JSON string looks like this:

```
{
    "8": {
        "67": [
            [
                {
                    "id":"64",
                    "description":"string description..."
                },
                {
                    "id":"65",
                    "description":"string description..., "
                },
                {
                    "id":"66",
                    "description":"string description..."
                }
            ]
        ],
        "41": [
            [
                {
                    "id":"64",
                    "description":"string description..."
                },
                {
                    "id":"65",
                    "description":"string description..., "
                },
                {
                    "id":"66",
                    "description":"string description..."
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

Notice that `['8']['67']` is an array with numeric indexes. To do what it looks like you want to do, your JSON string should look more like this: ([sample](http://codepad.org/TVtWd7NK))

```
{
    "8": {
        "67": {
            "64":"string description...",
            "65":"string description..., ",
            "66":"string description..."
        },
        "41": {
            "64":"string description...",
            "65":"string description..., ",
            "66":"string description..."
        }
    }
}
```

And so your PHP array should look more like this:

```
$considerationCodes = array(
    "8" => array(
        "67" => array(
            "64" => "string description...",
            "65" => "string description..., ",
            "66" => "string description..."
        ),
        "41" => array(
            "64" => "string description...",
            "65" => "string description..., ",
            "66" => "string description..."
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking.  How do I format my array to look like that?

Comment: I edited my original question and updated with the array construction.

Comment: The last part of my answer shows how to create an array with that structure in PHP. I don't have time today to modify your array construction code, but in the meantime, [here](http://codepad.org/Rr0NwYjP) is a way to convert your existing array to the proper structure.

Comment: Tried to reformat according to your example, I get the following error: Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object on this line: $considerationCodes[$key1][$key2][$value4->id] = $value4->description;  And the printout looks like: {"8":{"67":{"":null},"41":{"":null},"42":{"":null},"43":{"":null},"44":{"":null},"45":{"":null},"46":{"":null},"47":{"":null},"48":{"":null},"49":{"":null},"50":{"":null},"51":{"":null},"68":{"":null}}}

Comment: Don't use the `json_decode` part. That was just for me to get an array like you already have. Start at line 5 in my example.

Comment: Yeah, I did, it still didn't work.  I went back to my array creation, and was able to get rid of one of the brackets, and was able to find out where the 2nd one was being inserted, but I can't figure out how to get rid of that last one in this foreach statement: $declinedConsiderationCodes = array();
        foreach($codes_with_reasons as $key => $value)
        {
            $declinedConsiderationCodes[$declinedAppStatus][$key]=[$value];
        }
        $considerationCodes = $declinedConsiderationCodes;

Comment: Remove the square brackets around `[$value]`.

Comment: OMG.  That did it.  I'm array retarded.  Thank you.  Everything works perfect now.